# Explain CRDs in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

Could some one explain me what are custom resource definitions (CRD's) and how it is useful ?
what are its practical applications  in kubernetes ?.

thank yoiu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom Resources Definitions is a way to extend a Kubernetes cluster API

It is useful, for integrators shipping applications to Kubernetes, as you may write your own controller, managing your application lifecycle: initialization, upgrades, backups, ...

It is useful to Kubernetes administrators, which could easily operate complex applications, without the hustle of managing lower-level resources.

You would find tons of practical use cases, postgres operators, percona, kafka, codeready-workspaces, nvidia gpu operator, argocd, tekton, ... Which would rely on such custom objects.